# Expanded in SingleChildScrollView crashes the application

Tags: flutter, image, stretch, fitted-box

I'm trying to make an application on Flutter. I ran into a problem: I can't make the images stretch in width.

I need 2 columns, each  has an image, each column should be 50% of the width of the screen, and stretch  image with column. Everything works as shown in the picture, until I insert it into SingleChildScrollView. After that, the application crashes until I set the exact height of the image.

[image]

Question: how to do this **WITHOUT** specifying the height of the image? I can't set height anywhere inside Row, because I don't know exact size а the image.

Comment: you want show each image in screen height and half of screen width?

Comment: half the width of the screen, BUT keeping the original proportions of the image height

Comment: Can you share your code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this:

```
SingleChildScrollView(
              scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
              child: Row(
                children: [
                  Expanded(
                      child: Image.asset(
                    'assets/images/test.jpeg',
                    fit: BoxFit.contain,
                  )),
                  Expanded(
                      child: Image.asset(
                    'assets/images/test.jpeg',
                    fit: BoxFit.contain,
                  ))
                ],
              ),
            ),
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try flexible instead of expanded

```
SingleChildScrollView(
              scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
              child: Row(
                children: [
                  Flexible(
                      child: Image.asset(
                    'assets/images/test.jpeg',
                    fit: BoxFit.contain,
                  )),
                  Flexible(
                      child: Image.asset(
                    'assets/images/test.jpeg',
                    fit: BoxFit.contain,
                  ))
                ],
              ),
            ),
```

Comment: Images do not expanding larger, than their original width.